# How can I merge video files of the same format/encoding together?

Tags: video

I have two sets of files which I'd like to merge.

The first is a set of dual audio ogm files at the same format. They are episodes of an anime, basically.

The second set is a pair of wmv's which are also the same format, though these don't have dual audio.

I'm on debian/linux and I have ffmpeg but I can't seem to find a decent guide to merging. If anyone can point me in the right direction or even advise a different application ( though it has to be linux compatible ) I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this helps

mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy part1.avi part2.avi -o complete.avi

Comment: hm. i think the audio is a little off, every so often it "glitches" in the audio. are there any settings to preserve the audio even more?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try avimerge from transcode package ?